# How to read content of response body using the Fetch API during 500 response code

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

UI code uses [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API to send a post request to download files and the backend (spring boot) throws 500 response code with a custom error message in the response body. I can see the custom message in the Postman client but not able to read it on UI using `response.body`. How do I read the contents in the response body?

My code snippet is like

```
return fetch(url, options)
.then((response) => {
  if(response.status === 200){ 
    return response.text();
  } 
  else if(response.status === 500){
  // read content of response body and display an alert with the custom message
  }
})
.catch((error) => {
 throw error;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll disagree from the statement proposed that says HTTP 500 usually doesn't come with a response body.  In my experience, I'd say is the opposite.

Anyway, as stated in the MDN website, the promise returned by `fetch()` will successfully resolve even for status codes like **500**.  This means that the method of extracting the body is the same for **200 OK** than for **500 Internal Server Error**.  You just need to know the format of the response body.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#body) the list of functions available in the response object that can help you read the body contents.  I'll enumerate quickly for completion:

1. Response.arrayBuffer()
2. Response.blob()
3. Response.formData()
4. Response.json()
5. Response.text()

Answer (score 0):

By modifying your current code like blow, you should be able to get your custom error message.

```
return fetch(url, options)
.then((response) => {
  if(response.status === 200){ 
    return response.text();
    } 
  }
})
.catch((error) => {
 // this is your custom error message
 const customErrorMessage = error.error.message
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions and this actually worked for me.

```
return fetch(url, options)
.then((response) => {
  if(response.status === 500){
    const error = await response.text();
    throw new Error(error);
  }
})
.catch((error) => {
 const customErrorMessage = error.message;
})
```